# The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'

Tags: mobile, flutter, visual-studio-code

Estou iniciando no flutter, porém me deparei com esse erro no setState.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Horímetro'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nome do operador:'),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefixo Trator:'),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefixo Implemento:'),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  '${formatDate(_data, [dd, '-', mm, '-', yyyy])}',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                new Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              final dtPick = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: new DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: new DateTime(2100));

              if (dtPick != null && dtPick != _data) {
           --->  setState(() {
                  _data = dtPick;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
```

não entendi muito bem no que estou errando, e fica dando esse erro ("The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'"). Quero saber como corrigi-lo.
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Opa, tudo bom? Uma dica é que você de uma olhada na [documentação](https://flutter.dev/docs), já que está começando. Esse problema pode ser por causa de você estar tentando utilizar o `setState((){})` dentro de um [StatelessWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) que é um _Widget_ estático. O _SetState_ apenas funciona nos [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário importar a biblioteca material.dart e utilizar um widget Stateful para utilizar o setState.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MeuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MeuWidgetState createState() => _MeuWidgetState();
}

class _MeuWidgetState extends State<MeuWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Deu certo!